# Pandas: how to iterate through two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:
df_b:

```
Bin         A     B     C   Proba-a   Proba-b   Proba-c    gamma
CPB%                                                            
0.00000     0    57  1728  1.000000  0.996368  0.926577  0.00000
0.00100     0  1579  1240  1.000000  0.895743  0.873890  0.00100
0.00200  1360   488   869  0.869532  0.864644  0.836966  0.00200
```

dfspread:

```
      spread Bin
0   0.000001   A
1   0.000002   A
2   0.000003   A
3   0.000004   A
4   0.000005   B
5   0.000006   B
```

What I need to do it to iterate through dfspread['spread'] using input from df_b. I also have to compute formula. What I tried so far is the following:

```
f= 0.00000001
max_exp = []
for index, row in dfspread.iterrows():
    for index,row in df_b.iterrows():
            exp = row['Proba-a']*(row['gamma']*row['spread']*(1+f)-(f+f))
            max_exp.append(float(exp))
```

But it does not work! Any idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: 1. You're defining the same name 'row' for both iteration cycles. Give them different names.
2. Do you want to calculate 'exp' for rows with the same index in 'dfspread' and 'df_b'?

Comment: You're totally right for your first point! My bad I am tired.... and for your point 2, no, the index does not matter.

Comment: So for each row in 'df_b', do you want to calculate the value of 'exp' for all the different 'spread' values in 'dfspread'?

Comment: for each row in dfspread I have to compute the exp, which is compute on iterating through the different values in the columns of df_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the job?

I also suppressed `index` using `_`, since you don't need it

```
f= 0.00000001
max_exp = []
for _, row1 in dfspread.iterrows():
    for _,row2 in df_b.iterrows():
            exp = row2['Proba-a']*(row2['gamma']*row1['spread']*(1+f)-(f+f))
            max_exp.append(float(exp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
# Spread values to an array
spread_values = [row['spread'] for index, row in dfspread.iterrows()]

f= 0.00000001
max_exp = []
for index,row in df_b.iterrows():
    for spread in spread_values:
        exp = row['Proba-a']*(row['gamma']*spread*(1+f)-(f+f))
        max_exp.append(float(exp))
print(max_exp)
```